# BULK INSERT type mismatch when table created from same .CSV

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssms

I receive update information for items on a daily basis via a CSV file that includes date/time information in the format YYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss

I used the Management Studio task "Import Flat File..." to create a table **dbo.fullItemList** and import the contents of the initial file.  It identified the date/time columns as type datetime2(7) and imported the data correctly. I then copied this table to create a blank table **dbo.dailyItemUpdate**.

I want to create a script that imports the CSV file to **dbo.dailyItemUpdate**, uses a `MERGE` function to update **dbo.fullItemList**, then wipes **dbo.dailyItemUpdate** ready for the next day.

The bit I can't get to work is the import.  As the table already exists I'm using the following

```
BULK INSERT dbo.dailyItemUpdate
FROM 'pathToFile\ReceivedFile.csv'
WITH
(
    DATAFILETYPE = 'char',  
    FIELDQUOTE = '"', 
    FIRSTROW = 2, 
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', 
    TABLOCK 
)
```

But I get a "type mismatch..." error on the date/time columns.  How come the `BULK INSERT` fails, even though the data type was picked up by the "Import Flat File" function?

Comment: I would suggest to create a format file foe the `BULK INSERT`. It is one of its parameters.

Comment: Maybe you have a non-printable character in there somewhere, or some extra comma, or some such thing. Can you truncate the file to the top 10 or 20 rows, and try that? See if that works, and proceed from there...load first 1/2 of the file, then 3/4, etc. Sometimes it's about trial end error.

Comment: Adding onto ASHs suggestions, check if the original data has embedded commas or newlines, which are typically handled as quoted strings in CSV files. Also check the CSV file newline style - \n (newline) or \r\n (carriage-return/linefeed). Another option is to load into a table full of NVARCHAR(MAX) columns and review the results - particularly the columns expecting numeric values or dates.

Comment: I have now tried using a format file and get the same error.  I've also checked for extra characters and can't find any.  One thing I do notice though is the date/time fields also have double quotes around them.  Could this be what's causing the problem?  If so how can I edit the format file to accept these in the same way the "Import Flat File" did?